# Website divs disappear with Position absolute

Tags: html, css, absolute

HTML:

```
<div class="site_wrapper">
    <div class="top_wrapper">
        <div class="top_bar_wrapper">
            <div class="nav_bar_wrapper">
                <ul>
                    <a href="#"><li>About Me</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Work</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Clients</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Contact</li></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     font-weight: 100;
     background-image: url(images/bg2.jpg);
    }
.top_wrapper{
    background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100px;
    }
```

So when I do this, it pushes the other divs up out of the screen, I want my nav bar on the image but I always want the img to be 100px from the bottom of the screen. Help me fix this!!!

Comment: Can you provide a http://jsfiddle.net displaying your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're giving height in percentage this would work in older IE. But not in latest browsers. To make it work you need to define the fix height in its parent div. To solve your issue, you can use:

```
html,body{
   height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi now try to this way add this **css** and remove `width` `100%` `height` `100%`

```
.top_wrapper{
    left:0;right:0;top:0;
    bottom: 100px;
    }
```

**Demo**

```css
body{
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     font-weight: 100;
     background-image: url(images/bg2.jpg);
  background-color:red;
    }
.top_wrapper{
    background:green url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    left:0;right:0;top:0;
  
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="site_wrapper">
    <div class="top_wrapper">
        <div class="top_bar_wrapper">
            <div class="nav_bar_wrapper">
                <ul>
                    <a href="#"><li>About Me</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Work</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Clients</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Contact</li></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked! One last question! My class site_wrapper still isnt covering the other divs what should I set to fix that?

Comment: now becuase your used to absolute position now more information absolute http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/